# No effect when doing git diff -- ':(exclude)package-lock.json'

Tags: git, package-lock.json

I want to a do a diff but without package-lock.json which is huge and is a generated file so nothing interesting for me there.
I tried both :

```
git diff -- ':(exclude)package-lock.json'

git diff -- ':!package-lock.json'
```

but it has just zero output. What am I doing wrong ?
I am running git 2.21.0

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior.  Are you sure you have unstaged changes in files other than package-lock.json?

Comment: yes I have 6 files unstaged as shown with git status

Comment: I did git status ---> "Changes not staged for commit:" and it lists all my changed files including package-lock.json.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Before using exclude pathspec you need to list non-exclude paths. Dot, for example, or a magic root `:/`:

```
git diff -- . ':(exclude)package-lock.json'
git diff -- . ':!package-lock.json'
```

Comment: thanks. I will try once I am back at work tomorrow .

Comment: Ok, actually I retested and found something very unintuitive: it has to be : git diff -- . ":(exclude)package-lock.json" .With simple quotes it will not work and will show the diff for every file including package.json.

Comment: What OS? Windows? In Unix/Linux/MacOS there is no such major difference between quote types.

Comment: Well the response is in your question i think... It is windows 10....

Comment: Yep, I see. I'm not a w32 user so I seldom remember that difference.

Comment: it is like living on a remote island far away

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to have to add arguments every time you run `git diff`, you can add a `.gitattributes` file to the root of your repository, and then add the following line to it (well, actually two lines, but the first line is an explanatory comment, and is optional):

```
#exclude package-lock from git diff
package-lock.json -diff
```

After you add that file you will be able to do a regular old `git diff`, with no additional arguments, and still not have to look at all the `package-lock.json` diff.